# Need to get this program checking if Number is prime but without if statement, how to make it work for 1? main can not be changed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Need to get this program checking if Number is prime but without if statement, how to make it work for 1? main can not be changed

```
#include <iostream>

bool prime(int x){

    for (int i = 2; i < x; ++i){
        return (x % i != 0);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << prime(1344) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend turning on your compiler warnings as well as stepping through this in a debugger. Both of those should be enlightening.

Comment: You always `return` a value on the first loop iteration.  Your function is equivalent to `return (x % 2 != 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns in the first iteration of the loop and only checks if the number is even or odd. Its basically the same as:

```
bool prime(int x){    
    return (x % 2 != 0);
}
```

For the special case of `x==1` you just need to add the condition that `x` can only be prime when it is not `1`. And we can break out of the loop by requiring that we did not find a factor yet in the loop condition. That is: We start by assuming that `is_prime = true` unless it is `1`, and stop as soon as we know that it isnt prime:

```
bool prime(int x){
    bool is_prime = true and (x != 1);
    for (int i = 2; i < x and is_prime; ++i){
        is_prime = is_prime and (x % i != 0);
    }
    return is_prime;
}
```

Note that the largest factor you need to check against is actually `sqrt(x)`, because if `x` has a divisor bigger than `sqrt(x)` then it must also have a divisior smaller than `sqrt(x)`.

PS: Not using an `if` is a rather artificial requirement. Even if the above solution has no `if`, it still has several branches. If you want a solution without branches, then this is not it.

Comment: @Damien ups fixed, now I understand what was meant with "how to make it work for 1" ;)

Comment: I would probably add to the loop condition so it breaks out of the loop as soon as `is_prime` becomes false.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude omg. My first idea for an answer was some prose that discusses that a `for` loop is an `if` in disguise, but I abandoned that idea to quickly. Will edit...

Comment: Can be simplified a little bit: `bool is_prime = x != 1; for (int i = 2; i < x and is_prime; ++i){ is_prime = x % i != 0;}` (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool prime(int x){
    int limit = sqrt(x);
    
    bool isPrime = 1^x; 
    for(int i=2; i <= limit; i++){
        isPrime &= (x % i != 0);
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

`bool isPrime =1^x`  is false for 1 and true for all other number.

and  `(x % i != 0)` always true for all prime number, and atleast one false for non prime number